# lose a jQuery behavior after first running of function

Tags: jquery, function

I have a table with some rows and inputs inside them. I want add a new row with its field whenever user press **+** key inside text box. I could do it, but the problem I have is that this function runs just for the first time. If I press **+** key on the second field, nothing won't happen.

[This is my code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUjYZ/5/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".data").bind('keyup',function(e){
        if(e.which == 107){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var content = $('#'+id).val();
            var newContent = content.replace('+','');
            $('#'+id).val(newContent);

            var current_rows = ($('#myTable tr').length);
            current_rows = parseInt(current_rows);
            var newId = current_rows + 1;

            var newRow = '<td><input type="text" class="data" id="'+newId+'" /></td>';
            $('#myTable tr:last').after(newRow);
            $('#'+newId).focus();
        }
    });
    $('#1').focus();
});
```

What I have to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using live instead of bind. But look in documentation I think live is obsolete now.

Comment: Oh really?   $(".data").bind('keyup',function(e){. Maybe you should read what you are posting.

Comment: If you change it to live it works. And BTW this code does nothing in Opera.